# Swift: enumerated starting at 1?

Tags: swift, loops, enumerate

In Swift, is it possible to enumerate a sequence starting at 1?

In my case, I'm using the [SQLite C interface](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) to [bind values to prepared statements](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html). The second argument of the `sqlite3_bind_*()` routines is the index of the SQL parameter to be set. The indices start at 1. (Ie, they're one-based.)

I could use [`Sequence.enumerated()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641222-enumerated) and just add 1 to `n` inside each iteration, like so:

```
for (n, value) in values.enumerated() {
  sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, Int32(n)+1, value)
}
```

But is there a way to start `n` from 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all collections indices in Swift are zero based but if you really want you can create your own custom enumeration zipping a range of Int32 values and the source collection:

```
extension Collection {
    var enumerated: Zip2Sequence<PartialRangeFrom<Int32>, Self> { zip(1..., self) }
}
```

---

usage:

```
let values: [Int32] = [10, 20, 30]

for (n, value) in values.enumerated {
    print("value:", value, "at:",  n)
}
```

---

This will print

```
value: 10 at: 1

value: 20 at: 2

value: 30 at: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, array indexes start at 0 in Swift, so if you want to have 1-based indexes out of the box, you'll need to write some extra code.

If you're only using the index once then any workarounds might not worth the effort, and the incrementing at the call site is the most straightforward solution.

If however you will need to use the incremented index multiple times within the loop, another approach you could take would be to shadow the index:

```swift
for (n, element) in [1, 2,3].enumerated() {
    let n = n + 1
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, Int32(n), value)
}
```

Another approach could be using `map()`:

```swift
for (n, element) in [1, 2,3].enumerated().map({($0+1,$1)}) {
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, Int32(n), value)
}
```

, however not sure if you gain much with this solution, as the code is a little bit obscure.